# angular 8 dropdown change event is not working

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using Angular 8 with Material Design.
I am trying to detect change event in my dropdown.

What am I doing wrong?
Did angular change some event names?

This is HTML code:

```
<mat-select (change)="onChangedSort($event)" [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option value="all">All</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="some_values">some other options</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

And this is Angular TS file code:

```
onChangedSort(event:Event){
    console.log(event);//nothing is happening here
    //some code
}
```

I tried with `selectChange` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `(selectionChange)`, not `(changed)`

https://material.angular.io/components/select/api